# thread priority security exception make sure the apk is signed

Tags: android, oculus, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I am trying to build my project in **oculus gear vr** using unity5 , but when I deploy my app I get the below error

```
thread priority security exception make sure the apk is signed
```

I have even created keystore

[image]

any suggestion why I might be facing this error in gear vr

Comment: https://answers.oculus.com/questions/4912/how-to-sign-a-native-application-for-gearvr.html

Comment: osig files are used for development only. They are device specific. 
remember to remove in production.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figure out the answer , to run apps in gear vr , you must have signature file for used device by get device id & use site below

https://developer.oculus.com/osig/

after you get the file , you should put inside your project in this directory

YourProjectName --- > assets --> Plugins ---> android ---> assets

> (notice if you don't find this directory make sure your build platform
>   **android** ,  from build setting -- > switch platform)

then what you if you get this error

> why this error happen  ??

when I work in project I copy signature file with its meta file

so to fix error , just copy signature file without its meta file

**UPDATED ANSWER**

How you can get device id?

There many ways to approach that but best way to write in terminal

```
adb devices
```

You should see a list of attached devices like this:

```
List of devices attached
    ce0551e7 device
```

[image]

or if you are lazy like me use this app its working very well it called 
[SideloadVR DeviceID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skyworxx.sideloadvrdeviceid&hl=en)

Comment: I downloaded an app ("Device ID") to help me find my Android Device ID for the oculus signature file creation.
After a lot of headscratching I discovered the provided ID was wrong.
Use the Android SDK provided 'adb.exe' tool to find your real device id.

Comment: In my case, with Unity 5.4, you need to create the folder by yourself, even if you switch to Android for build.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following the steps as below,

1. Get the device ID using the adb.

   For that, take the command prompt and type `adb devices`.

   Ensure that adb path is added in the environment variables.

   Also, you can use SideloadVR app to get the device ID.

   [image]
2. Used the device ID to generate the oculus signature file using the service at https://developer.oculus.com/manage/tools/osig-generator/

   [image]
   [image]
3. Copy the signature file generated in step 2 at the following location in your unity project sub folder - `Assets / Plugins / Android / assets` (Create the folders if that do not exist).
4. Now build and Run the App on an Android Device.

For more: [Oculus Signature File (osig) Generator](https://developer.oculus.com/manage/tools/osig-generator/)

Answer (score -1):

The above method didn't work for me, but I found that putting the signature file (osig) into "Project_Name/app/src/main/assets" does work. Within Android Studio you will see the file in your 'assets' folder too.

For example with the GearVRf Cockpit Demo, I put my osig file in:

```
GearVRf-Demos\gvr-cockpit\app\src\main\assets
```

Comment: The op was talking about Unity, not Android Studio.